# Horses may try ···

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I'm not exactly sure what I've put together here, but let's give it a go

> Boast that you know me, I look a bit like a ball
>   From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls
>
> Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile
>   But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile
>
> So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most"
>   They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

Hint 1:

> Not Humpty Dumpty
>  (I thought it would be cute to model it after Humpty Dumpty but the answer's more abstract)

Hint 2:

> The second line is the best place to look for the answer, tho the rest (except the 2nd last) hint at it.

Hint 3:

> The answer is a word but not a thing. Small like an egg but big in spirit. It's carefully hidden in the clues (Except the first line where it's sloppily hidden (really not happy with that line) and the 2nd last line where I just didn't bother).

Comment: As a non native English speaker, this riddle hurt my brain....a lot.

Comment: Yeah... as the author, mine too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ...

> the word **all**.
>  A word, small like an egg (3 letters) but certainly big in spirit, and an abstract word rather than a thing, let alone an edible thing.

Boast that you know me, I look a bit like a ball

> You would be boasting to say you know all.
>  The word "all" is, as hinted, sloppily hidden inside "ball".

From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls

> "all" is the end of "a wall", and is the greatest part of the word "falls".

Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile
But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile

> I'm somewhat at a loss for what you're going for with these lines.
>  I'm assuming here that "a" "l" "l" are key letters of "a lazy pile" and "tail"/"wile", but that feels unsatisfying.

So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most"

> (per OP, not a hinting line)

They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

> all-spice.  what you had in mind with the garlic loaf still escapes me.

Comment: Maybe the 'Horses may try ...' refers to the HD line 'All the king's horses  ..'

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if the [tag:steganography] tag would be appropriate here.

Comment: Well done. A few of the clues were pretty vague. "Lazy pile" was meant to be the word "all" scrambled within those two words. "More than a tail" was my way of saying the letters a-l-l are almost all there in "tail". And then "garlic loaf" was more of the same mixing of the letters a-l-l into the words.

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Humpty Dumpty, or more generally an EGG?

Much of the riddle refers to

> the old [nursery rhyme](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/46951):
>
>  Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall,
>  Humpty Dumpty had a great fall;
>  All the king's horses and all the king's men
>  Couldn't put Humpty together again.

As for being "shaped a bit like a ball",

> HD is usually portrayed as an egg. For example:
>
>  [image: pic]

These might also be found together with spice or in garlic bread. (I think so anyway? Cookery isn't my strong suit.)

Comment: No. Good guess, but that was just my inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Updated, are you...

> **Water**

Boast that you know me, I look a bit like a ball

> Water droplets are round and look like a ball

From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls

> Niagara Falls

Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile

> Horses is an anagram for 'shores'. With that reference I think you are talking about ocean tides scraping to the shores here

But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile

> But scraping cannot make-make water, it's made by complex chemical bonding

So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most"
They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

> When people feel something to be spicy, they drink water. And it is used to mix the dough for a loaf of garlic bread.

Comment: Good guess, but still more abstract than that. There's a reason it's so awkwardly worded (aside from lack of talent)... Really the second line is the only one that works well.

Comment: The last line, does it point to something edible?

Comment: No. It's a bit of a play on words. I was trying for 2 hints on that line, tho they're both pretty difficult. "pair me with spice" is maybe helpful but I'm sure "mix a nice garlic loaf" will only make sense after you've found the answer... Which is a word but nothing edible.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> Dominos

Boast that you know me

> Perhaps referring to Domino mask - It's a privilege to know a secret

I look a bit like a ball

> White with black spots, kind of looks like a soccer ball.

From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls

> Dominos fall...

Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile
But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile

> Could refer to the fact it takes intelligence to order dominos properly, more of a reference to the game.

So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most" They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

> Dominos Pizza has garlic crust, spices, paired with a logo of a domino.

Comment: Clever, but not what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to put this down for now, but a slight fit is:

> a barrel, but I don't see how you'd boast about knowing one.

Boast that you know me, I look a bit like a ball
From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls

> Kinda looks like a ball, a barrel ride over a waterfall.

Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile
But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile

> Barrel racing, scrape things and put it in a barrel,

So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most"
They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

Comment: Good guess, not it tho. It may be my fault. I'm really not happy with the first line...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this at all but could you be:

> Grain

Boast that you know me, I look a bit like a ball

> boasting aside because IDK, Grain can be pretty orb-like

From the end of a wall, I take the greatest of falls

> a reference to the grain being harvested?

Horses may try, scrape me into a lazy pile

> Horses (terrifying animals!) will happily eat grain and may even scrape it up into a pile first

But it takes more than a tail to piece together my wile

> You can't piece grain together without first grinding it down and adding other components

So with a sigh, the men they concede, "may as well make the most"

They'll pair me with spice or mix a nice garlic loaf

> Men use grain for many purposes including to make flower and thus to beak bread, and 'pairing with spice' could be any number of grain/spice dishes.

Comment: What?? Horses are great. And in this case "may try" is a bit of a stretch because they almost certainly wouldn't try... Unless they like word games.